# Showing "Thank you message" with AJAX and running php script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form and I want when someone click submit, run upis.js write thank you message and run php script for inserting into database. For now it takes values I can see them in my url but it doesnt run upis.php. Can you tell me why? 
Here is the code for form:

```
<form>
    <label>Ime</label>
    <input type="text" name="ime" id="ime" required><br>
    <label>Prezime</label>
    <input type="text" name="prezime" id="prezime" required><br>
    <label>Ime slavljenika</label>
    <input type="text" name="ime_slavljenik" id="ime_slavljenik" required><br>
    <label>Prezime slavljenika</label>
    <input type="text" name="prezime_slavljenik" id="prezime_slavljenik" required><br>
    <label>Kontakt email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    <button onclick="return upis()">Posalji</button>
    <div id="placefortableanketa">
    </div><br><br>
</form>
```

and upis.js

```
<script>
function upis(){

    var ime = document.getElementById("ime").value;
    var prezime = document.getElementById("prezime").value;
    var ime_slavljenik = document.getElementById("ime_slavljenik").value;
    var prezime_slavljenik = document.getElementById("prezime_slavljenik").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

    var dataString = "ime="+encodeURIComponent(ime)+"&prezime="+encodeURIComponent(prezime)+"&ime_slavljenik="+encodeURIComponent(ime_slavljenik)+"&prezime_slavljenik="+encodeURIComponent(prezime_slavljenik)+"&email="+encodeURIComponent(email);

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "upis.php",
        cashe: false,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data){
            //window.alert(data);
            document.getElementById("placefortableanketa").innerHTML = data;
        },
            error: function (req, status, err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong', status, err);
        }
    })
    return false;
}
</script>
```

and upis.php

```
<?php

require_once 'include/db.php';
require_once 'include/functions.php';

$allowed_params = allowed_post_params(['ime', 'prezime', 'ime_slavljenik', 'prezime_slavljenik', 'email','submit']);
// niz sadrzi dozvoljene maksimalne duzine za sva polja
$fields_lengths = ['ime' => 64, 'prezime' => 64, 'ime_slavljenik'=>64, 'prezime_slavljenik'=>64, 'email' => 64];

// provera da li su polja odgovoarajuce duzine
foreach ($fields_lengths as $field => $length) {
    if (!has_length($_POST[$field], ['min' => 0, 'max' => $length])) {
        header('Location: greska.html');
        die();
    }
}


try {
    // Priprema upita za unos podataka u bazu
    $prep = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO prijavljeni (ime, prezime, ime_slavljenik, prezime_slavljenik, email) VALUES(:ime, :prezime, :ime_slavljenik, :prezime_slavljenik, :email)");
    $prep->bindParam(':ime', $ime);
    $prep->bindParam(':prezime', $prezime); 
    $prep->bindParam(':ime_slavljenik', $ime_slavljenik);
    $prep->bindParam(':prezime_slavljenik', $prezime_slavljenik);
    $prep->bindParam(':email', $email);


    $ime = isset($allowed_params['ime']) ? $allowed_params['ime'] : "";
    $prezime = isset($allowed_params['prezime']) ? $allowed_params['prezime'] : "";
    $ime_slavljenik = isset($allowed_params['ime_slavljenik']) ? $allowed_params['ime_slavljenik'] : "";
    $prezime_slavljenik = isset($allowed_params['prezime_slavljenik']) ? $allowed_params['prezime_slavljenik'] : "";
    $email = isset($allowed_params['email']) ? $allowed_params['email'] : "";


    // izvrsavanja upita
    $rez = $prep->execute();
    $htmltable = "Hvala na poslatoj prijavi.";
    echo $htmltable;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'greska kod upita';

}


?>
```

I cant see what can be problem here because js takes values from form but doesnt actually run upis.php(it doesnt take url upis.php) I dont understand why..

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing your application using Firefox or Chrome look in the network tab of web inspector to ensure the JavaScript resource successfully sends an XHR request. Check the URL that the POST XHR request is sent to.

Is the URL set correctly in the url property of the AJAX settings?

You may need to prepend "upis.php" with a forward slash e.g. "/upis.php"

Comment: I havel tried with "/upis.php" but it wasnt helpful. How can I check XHR request?

Comment: When developing a jQuery AJAX JavaScript script use the Firefox network monitor (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) or the Chrome network panel (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#network) to gain insight into XHR requests and the server response.

Comment: I still have the same problem. Do you maybe see any kind of mistake in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You should call script from index.php, you missed action and method in form

```
<form action="upis.php" method="post">
            <label>Ime</label>
            <input type="text" name="ime" id="ime" required><br>
            <label>Prezime</label>
            <input type="text" name="prezime" id="prezime" required><br>
            <label>Ime slavljenika</label>
            <input type="text" name="ime_slavljenik" id="ime_slavljenik" required><br>
            <label>Prezime slavljenika</label>
            <input type="text" name="prezime_slavljenik" id="prezime_slavljenik" required><br>
            <label>Kontakt email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
            <button onclick="return upis()">Posalji</button>
            <div id="placefortableanketa">
            </div><br><br>
        </form>
```

Comment: For everyone who will maybe run on this question, I resolved it by including needed in head part, so my advice is to be carefull. Thank you @MPetrovic i resolved it.